# treat integers as key values rather than row indexes in `data.table[i`

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table where `key` field contains integer values:

```
mydt1 <- data.table(keycol1=10:20, col1=letters[10:20], key='keycol1')
```

Now I want to select records according to those values:

```
myIDs <- c(11, 15, 19)
```

But I can't just put those values as `[i` - they will be treated as row indexes:

```
mydt1[myIDs,] # it will try to query rows 11, 15, 19
#   keycol1 col1
#1:      20    t
#2:      NA   NA
#3:      NA   NA
```

For the moment, I use workaround of converting all to `character`:

```
myIDs <- as.character(myIDs)
mydt1$keycol1 <- as.character(mydt1$keycol1)
setkey(mydt1, keycol1)
mydt1[myIDs,] # this works as expected
```

What would be correct way of doing this?

Comment: NO. Don't convert to `character`. It works there because there's no other interpretation for subsets using character vector.. So we allow it *for convenience*. For other types, there's a default operation possible in base R. That'd be just confusing to subset on values of key column instead of default integer subset. Use the `.()` notation. If you've set key, then `mydt1[.(myIDs)]` should use key based subsets. But I'm repeating myself. Please go through the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: thanks! I have read vignettes too long time ago, clearly time to refresh...

Comment: No worries. If you find any issues or something unclear or something needs to be added, please write under [#944](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a binary join as you already have the `key` set.

```
mydt1[.(myIDs)]
#    keycol1 col1
# 1:      11    k
# 2:      15    o
# 3:      19    s
```

P.S.

Just saw @Aruns comment, so as he said, you should definitely read [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you ask for

```
> mydt1[ keycol1 %in% myIDs ]   # also succeeds with mydt1[ keycol1 %in% myIDs , ]
   keycol1 col1
1:      11    k
2:      15    o
3:      19    s
```

Comment: you're right, it also solves the problem in my example, thanks! (However, the solution with `[.(myIDs)]` looks better for me because it does not re-order IDs and keeps duplicates, for example if `myIDs <- c(15, 11, 11)`)